# Unable to download extensions automatically and even the marketplace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner into coding and I wanted to learn java. So I found some tutorials online and they were pretty easy to follow. Also, I use visual studio code. Now my problem is that every time I try downloading a extension from visual studio code, it gives me an error [as shown in this image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ni7w.png)

I tried installing it from the marketplace and from VSIX but when I added the file, it didn't say or do anything and did not install the extension. I've been looking throughout the internet for a way to fix this, but I can't seem to find any video or post on how to fix this. So, hopefully I  find some help here. Also, this is occurring with any extension I try to download. I hope to get a answer pretty soon.

Comment: The attached image suggests looking at the log file and has a link to it. Did you try looking at that? Posting the contents here would probably allow you to get better answers. If all else fails, try using IntelliJ Comunity instead of VS Code.

Comment: Yes, the link leads to the marketplace version of the extension which I already tried and did not work.

Comment: Wait. The link for the log file leads to the marketplace? Or did you click the "Try Downloading manually" button?

Comment: This is probably an extension cache issue. You could try this: uninstall VSCODE, then delete   %APPDATA%\Code (type that into the  "Run..." window and you'll get to the folder. Note that this will delete all previous VSCode configuration. Then reinstall Code and the extensions again.

Comment: Welcome! 1) Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). 2) paste the contents of the log into your question post.

Comment: The log link leads to the console which says

 Error: Unable to read file 'vscode-userdata:/c:/Users/TopiZ/.vscode/extensions/extensions.json' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'vscode-userdata:/c:/Users/TopiZ/.vscode/extensions/extensions.json')

I also tried searching this up but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Deleting code from appdata did not seem to repair the issue.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: 1) possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174055 2) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.